Unable to create partitioned table in Databricks on external data residing on ADLS
I am copying files from ftp to ADLS in bronze folder under the partitioned folder heirarchy like
bronze
   |
   |
   +----- __run_date__=2023-10-23
                    |
                    |
                    +---- file__2023-10-23.csv
                    
   |
   |
   +-----__run_date__=2023-10-30
                    |
                    |
                    +---- file__2023-10-30.csv


                
                

where this folder is getting created dynamically at ADF copy activity sink side.
Csv file has 3 columns - sid, country, site
Now in Databricks I have created a External table with CSV format which will read the files present on above ADLS location. and when we refresh the table we would be able to query data from the external bronze table.
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS externaldata.table__bronze__websites_test2 (
  sid        INTEGER, 
  country        STRING,
  site        STRING,
  __run_date__   DATE
)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (header = "true",delimiter=";")
PARTITIONED BY (__run_date__)
LOCATION '{EXTERNALDATA_DATALAKE_NAME_ADLS}'

it will have 4 columns sid, country, site, __run_date__ (which is generated automatically)
Now when i try to partition this bronze table by adding PARTITIONED BY clause in CREATE TABLE statement for __run_date__. column
Then table gets created but when I query it. It fails to read the table and gives 0 output.
I found out thorugh the spark documentation that if the partitioned table is created from existing data, partitions are not registered automatically in the Hive metastore. User needs to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE to register the partitions.
but when i try to execute MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_identifier this command. I get following error.

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failure to
initialize configuration for storage account
[REDACTED].dfs.core.windows.net: Invalid configuration value detected
for fs.azure.account.keyInvalid configuration value detected for
fs.azure.account.key

How can i solve this problem?

It seems that your configuration for the storage account is invalid, or the location path you provided is incorrect. To set the Spark configuration using the account key, use the code below:
spark.conf.set(
    "fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net",
    dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope>", key="<storage-account-access-key>"))

Refer to this for more information on configuring the storage account with Sas tokens and Azure service principal.
Provide the location with the abfss protocol:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS externaldata.table__bronze__websites_test2 (
  sid        INTEGER, 
  country        STRING,
  site        STRING,
  __run_date__   DATE
)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (header = "true", delimiter=";")
PARTITIONED BY (__run_date__)
LOCATION 'abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>"'

If MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_identifier still doesn't work, manually alter the table to add partitions using the example SQL code below:
ALTER  TABLE  table_identifier ADD  IF  NOT  EXISTS  PARTITION  (__run_date__=2023-10-23)  PARTITION  (__run_date__=2023-10-30);

and
ALTER  TABLE  table_identifier  PARTITION  (__run_date__=2023-10-23,  __run_date__=2023-10-30)  SET  LOCATION  '/path/to/part/ways';

Learn more about this command here.

@yash394 Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
